# The purpose of reduce after filter and why map is called inside the filter?

Tags: javascript

I kind of confused first why we use a `map` function within a filter and what `reduce` does in this code. I'm  still learning and this puzzles me, help please.

This what this code should do:

> Function that looks through an array of objects (first argument) and
>   returns an array of all objects that have matching name and value
>   pairs (second argument). Each name and value pair of the source object
>   has to be present in the object from the collection if it is to be
>   included in the returned array.

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  var srcKeys = Object.keys(source);
  // filter the collection
  return collection
.filter(x => srcKeys.map(y => x.hasOwnProperty(y) && x[y] === source[y])
.reduce((a, b) => a && b))
}

// test here
console.log(
  whatIsInAName([{
    "apple": 1,
    "bat": 2
  }, {
    "bat": 2
  }, {
    "apple": 1,
    "bat": 2,
    "cookie": 2
  }], {
    "apple": 1,
    "bat": 2
  })
)
```

Comment: Do you know how reduce works? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce - Also there's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND

Answer (score 0):

1st argument (collection) will be handling the main source of bunch and the 2nd argument (source) will be handling the exact row to be search.
In above case, returned result will be consist of array of objects in which full row will consist of main source of bunch.
So, it will return the object if both the keys (apple & bat) available in collection object.